# The construction of "Known but to God"

Tags: meaning, phrases, conjunctions, negation

The [Tomb of the Unknown Solider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomb_of_the_Unknowns) has the engraving "KNOWN BUT TO GOD", as presumably no man knows his name, but shouldn't it read "*un*known, but to God", as the default for everyone is "unknown", with the exception "but to God"?

Is the construction older?  How should it be parsed?

Comment: Gravestones of unknowns in Commonwealth cemeteries are inscribed "Known unto God".

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In the phrase

> Known *but* to God

*but* functions as an adverb, and, as such, it means *only*. Thus, the inscription could very well read:

> Known *only* to God

Comment: So the comma I figured was implicit doesn't belong there at all, as it changes the meaning?

Comment: @Nick T: Right, the comma doesn't belong there. With the comma, *but* becomes a preposition, which means *except*!

Answer (score 0):

The tomb of the unkown soldier, or any of the graves at Arlington that are inscribed with the same quote for that matter, have a comma so the point made regarding that is moot. Just because someone posts something with it that way doesn't mean it's accurate.

I don't think the language used at the time makes any difference. If you are focused on that maybe take a step back for a few seconds and think about how strange it sounds to be concerned with the wording considering the gravity of why it was used.

Comment: Please provide a reference that these have a comma. I don't see one in the 4th picture [here](http://imgur.com/gallery/0DrnE).