# What does "but" mean in "Life is but a dream"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The construction of “Known but to God”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9235/the-construction-of-known-but-to-god)

What does "but" mean in this case and what other uses is this word used in the same context. I'm trying to explain what this word means but I can't think of any good common use examples with the same meaning.

The clearest word I can think of is "just"

*Life is just/only a dream*

Example sentences I did think of used "nothing":

I found nothing but junk at the store.

But is this the same meaning?

I found nothing, *just* junk, at the store?

Comment: There's nothing more to say. You've answered your own question. You are correct :)

Answer (score 18):

I've always interpreted phrases of that sort having an entire word (*nothing*) elided out, as in:

`Life is [nothing] but a dream`

The [popularity trend](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+nothing+but+a%2Cis+but+a&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) of the phrase "is nothing but a" versus "is but a" indicates the frequency of the poetic latter formulation is trending down towards that of the former, to a point about 20 years ago where they are nearly equal in occurrence.

Comment: Well, I think 'nothing' shouldn't be assumed.  It's kind of nostalgic, and nothing turns it into a real downer.  I think 'but a dream' is supposed to be ironic, at least, if you want to append that.

Answer (score 8):

According to [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/but), this usage is as an adverb, meaning "merely" or "only".

e.g. Hopes that lasted but a moment.

Comment: I agree.  "Just" also fits, as you suggested, At0mix.  Hey, how did you get that weird character on your name?

Comment: @Wolf copy and Paste, mate.

Comment: It's a Dutch character. On a Mac, Option+o.