# Omitting "nothing" in "nothing but"

Tags: grammaticality, grammar, word-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The construction of “Known but to God”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9235/the-construction-of-known-but-to-god)
>   [Difference between “but” and “nothing but”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65780/difference-between-but-and-nothing-but)

Is it acceptable to omit the word *nothing* in the following sentence?

> Knowledge was **nothing but** a tool.

I remember hearing somewhere the sentence

> You are **but** a fool!

To my ear, omitting *nothing* makes it sound more dramatic, but I’m not sure.

Comment: @Nate Duplicate questions don't count as duplicates. You should pull the original instead.

Comment: @KitFox: Indeed, [44900 "Life is but a dream"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44900/what-does-but-mean-in-life-is-but-a-dream) is closed as a duplicate of [9235 "Known but to God"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9235/the-construction-of-known-but-to-god).  But I don't think they are really duplicates, as in "but a dream" it seems that "but" is acting as a preposition, while in "but to God" it is an adverb.  44900 has answers that seem more relevant to this question, so I cited it.

Comment: Yes: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9235/the-construction-of-known-but-to-god -- "nothing but" means "nothing except"; just "but" means "only". 9235 says that (although you need to read the comments).

Comment: @AndrewLeach Given that comments are temporary, it's not sufficient to point to another question as a dupe on the strength of comments. I'm not saying that's what you are doing necessarily – it may be a dupe of that question anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Knowledge was nothing **but** a tool

means

> Knowledge was nothing **except** a tool

while

> Knowledge was **but** a tool

means

> Knowledge was **only** a tool

It turns out that the two meanings of *but* give sentences which have similar meanings!

Comment: I'd say "nothing but" = "only", so what's the difference?