# Secular phrase for "Heaven only knows" or "God only knows"?

Tags: phrases, synonyms

As the title states, I am seeking a secular phrase synonymous to "Heaven only knows" or "God only knows." Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 68):

"Who knows?" is the simplest form. I hear it (and use it) regularly.

Answer (score 35):

This one involves swearing, but this is a fairly common way to express the same idea:

> "Fuck only knows"

or just

> "Fuck knows"

Answer (score 27):

The literal intended meaning of this phrase is "nobody knows".  As an atheist, I don't believe there is a God.  Therefore, I can still say "God only knows" because the intended meaning of "nobody knows" logically follows from these premises.

Answer (score 26):

If you are from 1950s England, you could say

> goodness only knows.

Answer (score 25):

How about "It's anyone's guess"?

Answer (score 12):

Secular phrase you seek.  Quote Yoda you can.

> Difficult to see. Always in motion is the future..

Answer (score 11):

A secular phrase to the idiom "God only knows"

- **It's impossible to say**. - "God only knows how he managed to find out where I lived." http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/god-only-knows

Another choice woule be

- "**Nobody knows and neither do I**". - "God only knows where I've left my keys".

Answer (score 9):

Most people I know are atheists and we happily use "God knows" and "Oh my god", without reverence or irony. Like all language, it's just a term that has universal currency - the archaic reason for why it exists is really just interesting more than important. In the unlikely event that the world reverts back to a place where it's really important that we constantly demonstrate our atheism, maybe a new term will arise.

Answer (score 5):

A humorous, colloquial version playfully ascribes omniscience to a person:

> Only [Chuck Norris](http://www.chucknorrisfacts.com/) knows.

In Stack Overflow culture, this would be:

> Only [Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) knows.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something that is **truly** not a minced version, the only thing I can really think of is:

> It's a mystery to me.

Or for a cheerier feel, "It's a mystery to me!"

Famous example usage:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YD1APGofTSk

(If you can sit through the 1'59" musical intro before the singing starts - remember the 80s?!)

Answer (score 1):

A reason for saying that “God only knows” is that it would be impious or irreverent to suggest that He (who knows everything) does not know.

For that reason, you get [expressions like this one on the Tomb of the Unknown Soldier](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/9235/9548).

A corresponding secular phrase could be simply, "I don't know", "No-one knows", "It's unknown", or "It's a mystery".

Answer (score 0):

How about **fate only knows**. Since the religious version implies that the future is predetermined and known. ([Fate](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fates) is still a Greek religious concept)