# Isn't 'but' unnecessary here?

Tags: word-usage

> You have but to be attracted by anything, to fall in love with it, you become engrossed with it, and all else goes for nothing, and you won't even look at it.

Doesn't this mean the same if the sentence was -

> You have to be attracted by anything, to fall in love with it, you become engrossed with it, and all else goes for nothing, and you won't even look at it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The construction of "Known but to God"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9235/the-construction-of-known-but-to-god)

Comment: No, the "but" changes the meaning to "you merely have to be", "all you have to do is be". "You must give me money" is not the same is "All you have to give me is a dollar".

Answer (score 1):

In that sentence, "but" means "only". "You have only to be attracted...".